# Give all numbers same amount of digits (notepad++ / regex)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ and regex to clean-up and format a text file that contains file names and sizes, as well as a lot of unnecessary information that I'm deleting.

To keep formatting consistent, I want all of the file sizes to contain the same amount of digits, by giving them leading zeros (EG: 17,100,200 would become 017,100,200)

Comment: Are you using some programming language to do that or  do you want to use find and replace from notepad++ using regex? If you are trying the latter that's pretty much impossible.

Comment: With PHP is as easy as using this...http://php.net/manual/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this 8 times **find: \D([0-9]{1})\D
replace:  00000000$1** to use, just increment the number in the curly brackets and delete a 0 in the replace. NOTE: you need to have regular expressions checked.